# How to put an image in the background in .html.erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm trying to integrate the Clean Blog bootstrap template into my Rails blog application, however, there is a section in the code which doesn't show up.

As you may see in the first line (http://pastebin.com/rV1qxv2y) it embeds an image as background, however in the application it doesn't work because the image is in the assets/images/ directory, so I would like to know what is the proper way to embed an image which is in that directory.

I already tried with http://pastebin.com/PYTUJmtn but none seems working.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The solution was <%= image_path("home-bg.jpg") %> thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `background-image: image-url('filename.ext')`.

When using the asset pipeline in Rails, the paths to assets in your app can't be referenced in a traditional way (i.e. simply writing out the path to the asset). However Sprockets does provide some [useful helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass) to help with this.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It doesn't work, when I try to use style="background-image: image-url('<%= assets_path/home-bg.png %>) or style="background-image: image-url('<%= images_path/home-bg.png %>) it returns an error "undefined local variable or method"

Comment: Try passing only the filename to `image-url` - the `<%= asset_path/... %>` is not needed here.

Comment: Did you make sure to put the filename in quotation marks? I notice in your pastebin link your asset paths are not passed in as strings as they should be.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your helper function, try calling `asset_path(...)` instead, without the s. See if that works.

Comment: With <%= asset_path(images/home-bg.png); %> it returns undefined local variable or method `images'

Comment: @Oxyrus Try passing in the argument as a string. That should resolve the error you're getting.

Comment: Put it in quotes and delete the semicolon: <%= asset_path("images/home-bg.png") %>